# How to list the top n frequent words in a string array in Java?

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I need to analyse a text and find the top n frequent words there. Where n is a number of frequent words to be printed which a user can specify
I used hashmaps for this. But for now, I can only find one most frequent word

Supposing I have such a hash map

```
    cat: 4
    dog: 3
    sky: 10
    blue: 1
```

My code to find the most frequent word looks like:

```
        int compareValue = 0;
        String compareKey = "";

  for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> set : pairs.entrySet()) {
            if (set.getValue() > compareValue) {
                compareKey = set.getKey();
                compareValue = set.getValue();
            }
        }
```

Could you please advise me how I can modify this code to find more than 1 most frequent word? And having a variable to specify the required number of frequent words

Comment: What you need is a `TreeMap`. This  requires you to provide your own `Comparator`.  Your `Comparator` should allow ordering by the value in each key-value pair.
You can then call `addAll(HashMap)` on your Treemap. Then lookup `TreeMap`'s `headMap()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer:

```
        String text = "Very very very good text to compare good text with cats, cats and dogs. " +
                "Very good dogs.";

        int mostFrequentWordsNumber = 5;

        Map<String, Integer> mapOfFrequentWords = new TreeMap<>();

        String[] words = text.split("\\s+");

        for (String word : words) {
            if (!mapOfFrequentWords.containsKey(word)) {
                mapOfFrequentWords.put(word, 1);
            } else {
                mapOfFrequentWords.put(word, mapOfFrequentWords.get(word) + 1);
            }
        }

        Map<String, Integer> sorted = mapOfFrequentWords
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                .limit(mostFrequentWordsNumber)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e2,
                                LinkedHashMap::new));
        System.out.println(sorted);
```

Result will be: `{good=3, Very=2, dogs.=2, text=2, very=2}`. You can change it to case insensitive to get rid of Very and very as different words.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve questions related to "Top K Elements" is by using Heap Data Structure. I would have used Heap to find the top k frequent words as per your question.
A sample code can be viewed on this website https://aaronice.gitbook.io/lintcode/heap/top-k-frequent-elements